# GWT textbox add a button

Tags: java, html, css, gwt

I have a text box where i am trying to get a button in the textbox.
I know this is a little tricky with GWT.

I have a HorizontalPanel where i am adding the textbox.

```
HorizontalPanel bar = new HorizontalPanel();
bar.addStyleName("indexBar");
bar.setVerticalAlignment(HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
bar.add(new Label("Select Accounts"));
bar.add(accounts);
Label fname = new Label("Search First Name");
fname.setStyleName("firstNameLabel");


firstNameSearch = new TextBox();
bar.add(fname);
bar.add(firstNameSearch);
```

I have seen this can be done using html/css, i am just unable to figure it out with GWT.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

this can be done by wrapping - try using the static wrap method with TextBox -

```
//method - static 
TextBox.wrap(Element element)
// "Creates a TextBox widget that wraps an existing <input type='text'> element."
```